# do something when a custom dialog is closed

Tags: android, listener, onclicklistener

I have a class that extends from Dialog, that class is my Custom dialog. Now, what I have is a code that show the dialog, but it's executed in a OnClickListener of a button. The following code is my actual code:

```
colorpicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("initial"+color);
        dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(Main.this, color);
        dialog.show();
        color=dialog.getfinalColor();
        System.out.println("Final"+color);
        drawView.changePaint(weight, color);
    }
});
```

Whant I want is to execute:

```
color=dialog.getfinalColor();
System.out.println("Final"+color);
drawView.changePaint(weight, color);
```

when the dialog is closed.

I try to do :

```
while(dialog.isShowing==true){
    color=dialog.getfinalColor();
    System.out.println("Final"+color);
    drawView.changePaint(weight, color);
}
```

But the app not crashes but don't do nothing, the app don't work fine with that code.

Any idea to make something like a `onFinishDialogListener()`?

Comment: Do you want this to happen every time it is dismissed or only when they dismiss using s certain button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setOnDismissListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) to register a callback for when your dialog is dismissed.

Then you can run your code in this callback.

Comment: Ok, but it take me "Multiple markers at this line
 - OnDismissListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) in the type Dialog is not applicable 
  for the arguments (new OnDismissListener(){})" on eclipse

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem with the listener